# Geting batch size in keras custom loss

Tags: keras, loss-function

I am implementing a custom loss in keras, for example, a sum:

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    K.sum(y_true, y_pred)
```

Now, I want to normalize it by the batch size. Is it possible, to retrieve the batch size from y_true or y_pred?

Answer (score 2):

I would say this highly depends on how you have your code set up.  What type of model are you creating?  Are you not setting batch-size as a global parameter?  Can you not just use that?  Also, assuming y_true is a numpy matrix, can you just use: 
`y_true.shape[dimension_representing_batch_size]` as a means of getting the size?

Answer (score 2):

Your batch size is `y_true.shape[0]`

To normalized, which I assume you are looking for loss per observations what you need is below,

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(y_true, y_pred) / tf.constant(y_true.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32)
```

Or why not just take the mean?

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(y_true, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.sum(y_true, y_pred) / tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype=tf.int32)
```