# access batch size in keras custom loss

Tags: keras, tensorflow

Following [Geting batch size in keras custom loss](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45864/geting-batch-size-in-keras-custom-loss) does not work.

I use this custom loss with 1 statement to show the issue:

```
   def sharpe(y_true, y_pred, bweight, sampleSizeBatchA):
      sampleSizeBatch = tf.constant(y_true.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32)
      return 1.0
```

I get error message:

```
---> 87     model.add_loss( sharpe(label, pred, bweight, sampleSizeBatchA) )
     88     model.compile(loss=None, optimizer=Adam(
     89       learning_rate=learning_rate))

<ipython-input-308-ac3322700ddb> in sharpe(y_true, y_pred, bweight, sampleSizeBatchA)
     24 
     25     def sharpe(y_true, y_pred, bweight, sampleSizeBatchA):
---> 26       sampleSizeBatch = tf.constant(y_true.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32)
     27       return 1.0
     28     def sharpeL(y_true, y_pred, bweight, sampleSizeBatchA):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in constant(value, dtype, shape, name)
    265     ValueError: if called on a symbolic tensor.
    266   """
--> 267   return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
    268                         allow_broadcast=True)
    269 

/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape, allow_broadcast)
    277       with trace.Trace("tf.constant"):
    278         return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
--> 279     return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    280 
    281   g = ops.get_default_graph()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
    302 def _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape):
    303   """Creates a constant on the current device."""
--> 304   t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    305   if shape is None:
    306     return t

/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    100       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    101   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 102   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    103 
    104 

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Add: this looks have something to do with eager execution. I disabled it using

```
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
```

But it still does not work.

Using
sampleSizeBatch = y_true.get_shape().as_list()[0]
does not work either.

```
<ipython-input-328-6b904c13605a> in sharpe(y_true, y_pred, bweight, sampleSizeBatchA)
---> 44       sampleSizeBatch = y_true.get_shape().as_list()[0]//counts
     45       for i in range(counts):
     46         endI = startI + sampleSizeBatch

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Comment: Try `tf.shape(y_true)[0], dtype=tf.int32)` instead of `y_true.shape[0], dtype=tf.int32`